# Jquery : trigger click and call a method with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#add-to').click(function(e){
      addNewLine(e,this.id);
});
```

the above code works when i click the particular element with id **add-to**

now I need to **automatically trigger** this click even and call the **same method (addNewLine(e,,this.id))** on click with parameters on loading the page .

Thanks for helping.

Refer [Here](http://jsbin.com/xisazexi/1/edit)

Comment: Use `$('#add-to').click()` or `$('#add-to').trigger('click')` on page load it will fire click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add-to').click() 
 });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add-to').trigger('click')
 });
```

Comment: but where i am calling the addNewLine method here ?

Comment: whenever you click that `#add-to` that will automatically call the assigned event that is `$('#add-to').click(function(e){addNewLine(e,,this.id);
});`

Comment: not manually, on page load automatically trigger the click event

Comment: it will call install the code in your file and check

Answer (score 1):

First off all what do you mean by automatic trigger?. You trigger some event when something happens like document is loaded etc

Let this event be like this only:

```
    $('#add-to').on('click',function(){
          addNewLine(e,,this.id);
    });
```

and whenever you have to trigger that element use:

```
     $('#add-to').trigger('click');
```

On triggering addNewLine() function will automatically called because its inside click event and whenever you trigger click, Click event you assigned earlier is also fired.

Comment: This will call `addNewLine()` twice, wouldn't it?